# Plotting Log scale in R

Tags: r, graph, statistics, plot, logarithm

I'm trying to plot a logarithmic scale, but I keep on getting this error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : invalid "log=1/h" specification.
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my code:

```
   #function
function(stepsize, temp_val, counter) {
  while(counter < 0) {
    counter <- counter + stepsize
    px_norm <- dnorm(counter, mean = 0, sd = .04)
    temp_val <- temp_val + px_norm }
  temp_val <- 2*temp_val
  temp_val <- temp_val *(stepsize/2)
  print(temp_val, digits = 12)
}

#Initial step size
h <- .01 
while (h > .00001) {
  x <- calc_error(h, 0, -5) #Gives me a result around .5
  err <- x - (exp(-.02)*0.5)
  plot(1/h, err, log = "1/h")
  h <- h/10 }
```

Basically, in this short function I'm trying to show as the step size increases, the error from the real answer will decrease. However, I'm having trouble plotting this. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is not a reproducible example. `#` is used for comments in R, not `//`. What is `calc_error`? we don't have that function.

Comment: That function works well, it gives a result around .5. I'm just having problems plotting

Comment: we have no damn clue what that function is. We can't read your mind. without `calc_error` we can't generate the data to plot anything. Also, makes no sense to plot each point inside the loop.

Comment: @Josh the function may work well but we do not have the function `calc_error`.  You would need to provide the code for this function if it is written by you or the package in which it can be found. Otherwise we can not reproduce your code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be an easy way to create the plot:

```
h <- 10^-seq(2, 4)
err <- lapply(h, function(x) calc_error(x, 0, -5) - (exp(-.02) * .5))
plot(1/h, err, log = "x")
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the post. I searched online for the function lapply, but I'm kinda confused with how it works/when you would use it. Also, in the call lapply(h, function(x), calc_error(x, 0, -5) - [...] why do you use "x" and not "h" since we are changing the values of x, or is it something like "pass by value"

Comment: The function is applied to all values of the vector `h`. A single value is indicated by `x` since I defined the function as a function of `x` (`function(x)`). Basically, `h` is the whole, but the function is applied to each element *separately*.

Comment: Also, when I use the lapply function, it shows me the calculation at every step, is there anyway to hide that?

Comment: @Josh This is due to the `print` command in your function. Just remove the line `print(temp_val, digits = 12)` and you will not see the output.

Comment: Is there a command which allows me to edit a function? Like edit or something? The problem is that I have a really weird version of R on Ubuntu and I use the terminal to access it (by typing R). I don't know how I can access the functions I have already created, so I have to create new ones.

Comment: If you're not comfortable with the command line, I'd recommend taking a look at RStudio ( http://www.rstudio.org ), which is a nice GUI that's available on all major platforms.

Answer (score 7):

```
plot(1/h, err, log = "1/h")
```

log should be the axis of your plot you want in log space, not the actual data.

i.e.

```
plot(1/h, err, log = "x")
```

will plot your x axis in log space

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to see a "log" graph, there is just a straight line on the x axis, but the x axis increments from 100 to 100000

Comment: @Josh Sounds more like you _are_ seeing a "log" graph, but that you've made some poor choices for your y scale. But just as with the `calc_error` issue, I'm not sure how you expect us to help without actually having your data in front of us.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want something like this:

```
i <- 1
h <- 0.01
err <- vector(0,mode="numeric")

while (h[i] > .00001) {
  x <- rnorm(1,mean=0.5,sd=0.05) #use calc_error instead
  err <- c(err,x - (exp(-.02)*0.5))
  i <- i+1
  h <- c(h,h[i-1]/10) }

plot(1/h[-length(h)],err,log="x")
```

Comment: Sven's code is better of course (or at least more in the spirit of R), but you are probably more familiar with a while loop.