# Spacing of x-axis with custom tick marks on log scale

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I have plotted my data in an ordinary scatterplot using `plot()`. I have defined the range of the x-axis to be between 0 and 1000 on a log scale. So far so good. But I have 3 different datasets, and for one of them, the spacing is 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, while for the other two the "1" is missing. I want all 3 plots to include the "1".

I tried with `xaxt="n"` and then `axis(1, at=c(0, 1, 10, 100, 1000))`.

The 1 is then plotted close to 0, so there is no log scaling between 0 and 1. I hope this is not too confusing. How do I manage to plot 0,1,10,100,1000 ALL at log scale, i.e. same spacing between all of these values?

I hope someone can help!

Comment: Have you tried setting `xlim` in `plot`?

Comment: Hopefully this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12554336/plotting-log-scale-in-r) will give you a hint

Comment: @fotNelton: Yes, I use xlim to define the range, but R seems to do the sacling of the ticks per default.

Comment: TWL: Is the hint that my post contains too little information? I am sorry, I am a really new-beginner. But I'll post the whole script if you like

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
#plot 1
# i don't know what your ylim should be but you want them to be 
# minimum across y1, y2, y3 and maximum across y1, y2, y3
plot(x1,y1,axes=F,xlim=c(0,1000),ylim=c(?,?),xlog=TRUE, col="red")
par(new=T)

#plot 2
plot(x2,y2,axes=F,xlim=c(0,1000),ylim=c(?,?),xlog=TRUE, col="blue")
par(new=T)

#plot 3
plot(x3,y3,axes=F,xlim=c(0,1000),ylim=c(?,?),xlog=TRUE, col="yellow")

#now put back in the axes
#y axis first
axis(2)
#x axis
axis(1,at=c(0, 1, 10, 100, 1000),label=c(0, 1, 10, 100, 1000))
box(bty="l")
```

What this does is make three graphs that have the same x and  y ranges; specifically, the x ranges for all graphs will be the same, 0 to 1000.  Both axes should span your data.  If they don't, you just need to extend the x or y.  Substitute the question marks in `ylim=c(?,?)` for some numeric values that will cover the range of your y values.

Once the data is plotted, then you add the `axis` statements to put in the ticks and labels.